# Combining polymorphic Mongoid model scopes in the base class?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have a simple bit of polymorphism where each subclass has a `dead` scope, each implemented slightly differently.  I would like to be able to gather them all together from a `dead` class method from the base class:

```
class Animal
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :birthday, type: DateTime

  def self.dead
    descendants.map(&:dead)
  end
end

class Dog < Animal
  scope :dead, ->{ where(birthday: { :$lt => Time.now - 13.years }) }
end

class GuineaPig < Animal
  scope :dead, ->{ where(birthday: { :$lt => Time.now - 4.years }) }
end

class Turtle < Animal
  scope :dead, ->{ where(birthday: { :$lt => Time.now - 50.years }) }
end
```

As defined, the `Animal::dead` method returns an array with each descendant model's scope criteria:

```
>> Animal.dead
=> [#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"birthday"=>{:$lt=>2000-08-23 14:39:24 UTC}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Dog
  embedded: false>
, #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"birthday"=>{:$lt=>2009-08-23 14:39:24 UTC}}
  options:  {}
  class:    GuineaPig
  embedded: false>
, #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"birthday"=>{:$lt=>1963-08-23 14:39:24 UTC}}
  options:  {}
  class:    Turtle
  embedded: false>
]
```

If I want to count up all my dead animals, I have to do something like this:

```
Animal.dead.map(&:count).reduce(:+)
```

What I would much prefer is if my `Animal::dead` method returned a regular `Mongoid::Criteria` of the combined scopes (ORed together) of each descendant's `dead` criteria, so I could simply do

```
Animal.dead.count
```

Any ideas for how this could be implemented?

If I were using DataMapper, it has a [nice feature](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html) where you can combine/"OR" scopes together using `+` or `|` (union operator).  I wasn't able to determine if Mongoid has such a feature, but if it does I think that would solve my issue.

Here's a quick RSpec spec of what I'm after:

```
describe Animal.dead do
  it { should respond_to(:count, :all, :first, :destroy) }
end

describe Animal do
  before do
    Animal.all.destroy
    # create 1 dead dog, 2 dead guinea pigs, 3 dead turtles (total 6)
    1.times{ Dog.create(birthday: Time.now - 20.years) }
    2.times{ GuineaPig.create(birthday: Time.now - 5.years) }
    3.times{ Turtle.create(birthday: Time.now - 100.years) }
    # create 3 alive dogs
    3.times{ Dog.create(birthday: Time.now - 6.years) }
  end

  it 'should combine descendant animal dead scopes' do
    expect(Animal.dead.count).to eq(6)
  end
end
```

I'm using Rails so you can assume I have ActiveSupport and all the other helpers available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a temporary solution that seems to work:

```
class Animal
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :birthday, type: DateTime

  def self.dead
    self.or(*descendants.map{|d| d.dead.type(d).selector})
  end
end
```

However, it seems hackish.  I will leave the question open for a while in case anyone has any cleaner suggestions.